# How to combine multiple images to make

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have linear layout with horizontal orientation and with multiple ImageView. How do I make single Bitmap with these images?

Like this:

[image]

If there are more than 6 images, then remaining images go in next lines.
This one is working for horizontal:

```
       Bitmap[] parts = new Bitmap[4];
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(parts[0].getWidth() * 2, parts[0].getHeight() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(parts[i], parts[i].getWidth() * (i % 2), parts[i].getHeight() * (i / 2), paint);
        }
```

Comment: Homework: expand code to handle the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You should take `LienarLayout`  in below method:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
v.draw(c);
return b;
}
```

pass your `LienarLayout` object in above method to take `Bitmap` from View.

Comment: but LL has horizontal orientation. If there are more than 6 Images in Linear layout, then remainin go to next lines.

Comment: So you need  to take bitmap of each line and then combined then yo make single bitmap.